# java.net.BindException: Permission denied Run via gradlew

Tags: gradle, openshift, cloudfoundry-uaa

I'm deploying uaa(https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa) to Openshift using DIY catridge. On executing `gradlew run`, I'm getting the following error:

```
remote: + '[' '!' -d /var/lib/openshift/54bd541be0b8cdd48e0001f0/app-root/data//gradle-2.2.1 ']'
remote: + cd /var/lib/openshift/54bd541be0b8cdd48e0001f0/app-root/runtime/repo/
remote: + export GRADLE_OPTS=-Dorg.gradle.bindaddress=127.3.86.1
remote: + GRADLE_OPTS=-Dorg.gradle.bindaddress=127.3.86.1
remote: + export GRADLE_USER_HOME=/var/lib/openshift/54bd541be0b8cdd48e0001f0/app-root/data//gradle
remote: + GRADLE_USER_HOME=/var/lib/openshift/54bd541be0b8cdd48e0001f0/app-root/data//gradle
remote: + export GRADLE_HOME=/var/lib/openshift/54bd541be0b8cdd48e0001f0/app-root/data//gradle-2.2.1
remote: + GRADLE_HOME=/var/lib/openshift/54bd541be0b8cdd48e0001f0/app-root/data//gradle-2.2.1
remote: + export PATH=/var/lib/openshift/54bd541be0b8cdd48e0001f0/app-root/data//gradle-2.2.1/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
remote: + PATH=/var/lib/openshift/54bd541be0b8cdd48e0001f0/app-root/data//gradle-2.2.1/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
remote: + ./gradlew run --stacktrace
remote:
remote: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
remote:
remote: * What went wrong:
remote: Could not open buildscript class cache for settings file '/var/lib/openshift/54bd541be0b8cdd48e0001f0/app-root/runtime/repo/settings.gradle' (/var/lib/openshift/54bd541be0b8cdd48e0001f0/app-root/d
ata/gradle/caches/2.0/scripts/settings_4q2fm2rl4vahfi2fl0nqac291k/SettingsScript/buildscript).
remote: > java.net.BindException: Permission denied
remote:
remote: * Try:
remote: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
remote:
remote: * Exception is:
remote: org.gradle.cache.CacheOpenException: Could not open buildscript class cache for settings file '/var/lib/openshift/54bd541be0b8cdd48e0001f0/app-root/runtime/repo/settings.gradle' (/var/lib/openshif
t/54bd541be0b8cdd48e0001f0/app-root/data/gradle/caches/2.0/scripts/settings_4q2fm2rl4vahfi2fl0nqac291k/SettingsScript/buildscript).
remote:         at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:48)
remote:         at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:28)
remote:         at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.doOpen(DefaultCacheFactory.java:80)
remote:         at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory.open(DefaultCacheFactory.java:50)
remote:         at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$PersistentCacheBuilder.doOpen(DefaultCacheRepository.java:138)
remote:         at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheRepository$AbstractCacheBuilder.open(DefaultCacheRepository.java:121)
remote:         at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.compile(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:57)
remote:         at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.ShortCircuitEmptyScriptCompiler.compile(ShortCircuitEmptyScriptCompiler.java:35)
remote:         at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.CachingScriptClassCompiler.compile(CachingScriptClassCompiler.java:36)
remote:         at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.DefaultScriptCompilerFactory$ScriptCompilerImpl.compile(DefaultScriptCompilerFactory.java:57)
remote:         at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:130)
remote:         at org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.applySettingsScript(ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.java:72)
remote:         at org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.process(ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.java:62)
remote:         at org.gradle.initialization.PropertiesLoadingSettingsProcessor.process(PropertiesLoadingSettingsProcessor.java:37)
remote:         at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsHandler.loadSettings(SettingsHandler.java:97)
remote:         at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsHandler.findSettingsAndLoadIfAppropriate(SettingsHandler.java:88)
remote:         at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsHandler.findAndLoadSettings(SettingsHandler.java:46)
remote:         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:120)
remote:         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:105)
remote:         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:85)
remote:         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
remote:         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
remote:         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
remote:         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
remote:         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
remote:         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
remote:         at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
remote:         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
remote:         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
remote:         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
remote:         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
remote:         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
remote:         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
remote:         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
remote:         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
remote:         at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
remote:         at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
remote:         at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
remote:         at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
remote:         at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
remote:         at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
remote:         at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
remote:         at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:56)
remote: Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.net.BindException: Permission denied
remote:         at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:39)
remote:         at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileLockCommunicator.<init>(FileLockCommunicator.java:40)
remote:         at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.getCommunicator(DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.java:156)
remote:         at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.reservePort(DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.java:148)
remote:         at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:79)
remote:         at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:67)
remote:         at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.open(DefaultCacheAccess.java:86)
remote:         at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.open(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:46)
remote:         ... 42 more
remote: Caused by: java.net.BindException: Permission denied
remote:         at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileLockCommunicator.<init>(FileLockCommunicator.java:38)
remote:         ... 48 more
```

I've upgraded to gradle 2.2.1 as discussed at https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2871. As I'm not doing a build of the project, just running it via `gradlew run`, I don't see any use of Jenkins here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Linux file permissions for that file?

SSH in and then navigate to that directory

then run 'ls -l' and it should probably look at least like

rwxrwxr-x

for the permissions

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. But I noticed that after modifying the permissions, it goes back to `-rw-------` whenever I re-run `gradlew run`

Comment: I take that back. I was looking at app-root/repo instead of app-root/runtime/repo. However, I changed the permission to 777 but I'm running into same issue.

Comment: hhhmmmm - not sure then

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, **Settings -> Gredle -> Global Gredle settings -> Service directory patch**

Change the folder.